# control return automatically and last line not executing in unit test case using mocha and chai

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm new in unit testing in node.js using mocha and chai.
I'm stuck at the problem in which control return automatically and not executing
chai.expect(123).to.be.a("string");

code is here

```
it.only("should fetch status",()=>{
        return chai.request(server)
        .get("/user/status")
        .then((result)=>{
            let data = result.body;
            console.log("till here execute");

            //this line is not executed and test case is passed even when the below line expect to fail the test
            chai.expect(123).to.be.a("string");
            
        })
        .catch(err=>err);
    });
```

Console show that above test case is passed I don't know how and why

```
chai.expect(123).to.be.a("string");
```

not executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to your `catch`.

Basically, when your `chai.expect` fails, it will throw an `AssertionError`.

Inside your given code, you are returning the catching error, and not throwing it.

According to chai.js official documents, found in https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/, when dealing with promises, inside the `catch` you must `throw` the catch error.

In that way, change:

```
.catch(err=>err);
```

to:

```
.catch(err => {throw err});
```